# How do I transfer held-item NBT data to a placed block in forge 1.20.1

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

#### What I am trying to achieve:

I am trying to transfer NBT data (otherwise known as Tags/CompoundTags) to a block that I get using "BlockEvent.EntityPlaceEvent". I want this to work like placing a sign or chest with NBT data stored inside of it does, where the placed block just inherits the NBT of what the held-item is.

Here is the non-working code I currently have:

```java
@SubscribeEvent
public static void onBlockPlacedBy(BlockEvent.EntityPlaceEvent event) {
    try {
        if (blockList.contains(event.getPlacedBlock().getBlock())) {
            ServerPlayer player = (ServerPlayer) event.getEntity();
            assert player != null;
            CompoundTag itemNBT = player.getMainHandItem().serializeNBT();
            CompoundTag blockNBT = Objects.requireNonNull(event.getLevel().getBlockEntity(event.getPos())).serializeNBT();
            broadcastMessage(blockNBT.getAllKeys().toString());
            if (itemNBT != null) {
                blockNBT.put("tag", Objects.requireNonNull(itemNBT.get("tag")));
                Objects.requireNonNull(event.getLevel().getBlockEntity(event.getPos())).deserializeNBT(blockNBT);
            }
            broadcastMessage("block placed: " + Objects.requireNonNull(event.getBlockSnapshot().getBlockEntity()).serializeNBT().getAllKeys());
        }
    } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

#### What I have tried:

I have searched for help online on how to do this, I wasn't able to find any useful documentation, I searched through various GitHub repositories for guidance on how to do this, and I have also searched through various new and outdated walk-throughs on YouTube to get some idea of what I should be doing and what I'm doing wrong, but I was not able to find anything useful. This is why I am now asking here.

I currently have this which doesn't work:

```java
if (itemNBT != null) {
    blockNBT.put("tag", Objects.requireNonNull(itemNBT.get("tag")));
    Objects.requireNonNull(event.getLevel().getBlockEntity(event.getPos())).deserializeNBT(blockNBT);
}
```

The code above and similar things have given me NullPointerExceptions.
Yes the item does have NBT data, I give it some data that is hardcoded in for testing purposes.

```java
BlockPos pos = new BlockPos(10, -54, 10);
CompoundTag locationTag = new CompoundTag();
locationTag.putInt("X", pos.getX());
locationTag.putInt("Y", pos.getY());
locationTag.putInt("Z", pos.getZ());
locationTag.putFloat("Yaw", 0);
locationTag.putFloat("Pitch", 0);
mainHandItem.addTagElement("SpawnLocation", locationTag);
```

Yet I cannot get the NBT data to transfer from the held item to the block.

Either a link to better documentation other than https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/1.20.x/, or a direct answer as to what I am doing wrong/what I should change would be appreciated.